# convert date in Month-Year format to last date of month

Tags: r, datetime

My dataset looks like this

```
dataset=data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),MonthYear=c("May 2015","April 2015","January 2016","February 2016","December 2018"))
```

I'd like to **add a column** to it that contains the **date of the last day of the month** for the given month-year (column `MonthYear`)

For example, the month-year `May 2015` would become `31-05-2015`

Using the `zoo` package I've tried to use `as.Date(as.yearqtr(MonthYear, "%b%Y"), frac = 1)` 
based on a solution I found on this forum, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lubridate` we can convert `MonthYear` to date object and use `ceiling_date` with `unit = "Month"` and subtract 1 day from it to get last day of the month.

```
library(lubridate)
ceiling_date(dmy(paste("01", dataset$MonthYear)), unit = "month") - 1
#[1] "2015-05-31" "2015-04-30" "2016-01-31" "2016-02-29" "2018-12-31"
```

Answer (score 3):

With `zoo`, instead of `as.yearqtr`, we use `as.yearmon` as the format is in 'Month Year'

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(dataset$MonthYear), frac = 1)
#[1] "2015-05-31" "2015-04-30" "2016-01-31" "2016-02-29" "2018-12-31"
```

Comment: I ran your solution, but I seem to be getting NAs instead of the dates

Comment: @Varun, The code shown in this answer works on the data your provided.  If you are getting NAs the problem is the question, not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that

1. your format is wrong.  The format shown in the question is for an abbreviated month followed by the year with no space between them.  In fact, the data has the full month name followed by a space followed by the year.
2. `yearqtr` is used in the code in the question but that is for year and quarter of a year whereas you have year and month of year.  Use `yearmon`, not `yearqtr`.

Making these changes yields the following code

```
transform(dataset, eom = as.Date(as.yearmon(MonthYear, "%B %Y"), frac = 1))
```

giving:

```
  ID     MonthYear        eom
1  1      May 2015 2015-05-31
2  2    April 2015 2015-04-30
3  3  January 2016 2016-01-31
4  4 February 2016 2016-02-29
5  5 December 2018 2018-12-31
```

Comment: I just noticed that an answer very close to this one was already posted but I leave it up due to the discussion and small differences which may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In base R we may add a month with `seq` and subtract a day.

```
as.Date(mapply(function(x) seq(x, length.out=2, by="month")[2] - 1, 
               as.Date(paste("01", dataset$MonthYear), "%d %B %Y")), 
        origin="1970-01-01")
# [1] "2015-05-31" "2015-04-30" "2016-01-31" "2016-02-29" "2018-12-31"
```

*Note:* `as.Date(dataset$MonthYear, "%B %Y")` won't work somehow, I don't know why...?

***Data***

```
dataset <- structure(list(MonthYear = structure(c(5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("April 2015", 
"December 2018", "February 2016", "January 2016", "May 2015"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: yep. `as.Date` requires a date component. It wouldn't work without that I think.

Comment: @RonakShah probably I unluckily expected `as.Date("June 2019", "%B %Y")` defaulting to `"2019-06-01"`

Comment: It works with `as.yearmon` though, `as.Date(as.yearmon(dataset$MonthYear))`

Comment: @RonakShah obviously easier in `zoo`